# Multi-tier architecture app with async http

Tags: android, asynchronous

I am coding an Android app, where it relies on an asynchronous web server.

My idea is to create the app with a multi-tier architecture, where communication is one tier, UI another and controller the third (of course model also has its own).

The problem I have is that the web server is asynchronous as I can't see how I can seperate it in tiers then. If it was a synchronous it would be very easy.

I am thinking of event-pattern, but then I have to create an event for each tier. But are there other possibilities?

I don't think AsyncTask is the solution since it would crash, if the user rotate the screen.

Comment: You might find this of interest: http://square.github.io/otto/

Comment: Thx for your help Ken, but why didn't you answer it instead of just comment it?

Comment: I don't feel like I can give a good answer to your question!

Comment: But Otto was just what I was looking for

Comment: Oh OK! It was just a guess. I have added it as an answer for completeness. It's a great libray (most of the square stuff is)

Comment: So if I have a question regarding Otto, I should just ask you?

Comment: Nah, just post a Question as normal and someone will answer hopefully. I'm not an expert :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94235/discussion-between-the87boy-and-ken-wolf).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at Otto:

http://square.github.io/otto/

> Otto is an event bus designed to decouple different parts of your application while still allowing them to communicate efficiently.

I think it might be what you are looking for.